# Event Listeners and Custom Events ExtJS

Tags: javascript, extjs, dom-events

The following code does exactly what I want it to do:

```
Ext.define('Animal', 
    {
        extend: 'Ext.util.Observable',
        name: 'Unknown',
        sound: 'Unknown',
        constructor: function(name)
        {
            this.name = name;
            this.addEvents('talk'); //not needed. AddListener(.on) creates the event in the Observable if it didn't already exist... - Animal www.sencha.com
            this.listeners = this.listeners;
            this.callParent(arguments);
            for(i = 0; i<arguments.length; i++)//callParent(arguments)? array(ish)
                console.log(arguments[i]);
        },
        makeSound: function() 
        {
            alert(this.name + " says " + this.sound);
            this.fireEvent('talk');
        },
        listen: function()
        {
            alert(this.name + " is listening.");
        }
    });

Ext.define('Cats',
    {
        extend: 'Animal',
        name: 'Unknown',
        sound: 'Meow',
    });
Ext.define('Dogs',
    {
        extend: 'Animal',
        name: 'Unknown',
        sound: 'Woof',
    });
var cat1 = Ext.create('Cats', 'Domino');
var cat2 = Ext.create('Cats', 'Tiger');
var dog1 = Ext.create('Dogs', 'Bruno');
var dog2 = Ext.create('Dogs', 'Spot');

cat1.on('talk', function(){dog1.listen()});
dog2.on('talk', function(){cat2.listen()});

cat1.makeSound();
cat2.makeSound();
dog1.makeSound();
dog2.makeSound();
```

dog1(Bruno) will listen for cat1.makeSound and respond with dog1.listen. 
Next up I want to try using listener config:

```
var cat1 = new Cats({
    name: 'Domino',
    listeners:
    {
    scope: dog1,
    talk: dog1.listen
    }
});
```

I seem to have trouble with getting it to work. Not sure if i am correctly using the syntax, having trouble finding examples of syntax. Let me know if you have an example or some information that will help me fix this problem. Following is the complete code I have for the listener config way of event handling:

```
Ext.define('Animal', 
    {
        extend: 'Ext.util.Observable',
        name: 'Unknown',
        sound: 'Unknown',
        constructor: function(config)
        {
            this.name = config.name;
            this.addEvents('talk'); //not needed. AddListener(.on) creates the event in the Observable if it didn't already exist... - Animal www.sencha.com
            this.listeners = this.listeners;
            this.callParent(arguments);
            for(i = 0; i<arguments.length; i++)//callParent(arguments)? array(ish)
                console.log(arguments[i]);
        },
        makeSound: function() 
        {
            alert(this.name + " says " + this.sound);
            this.fireEvent('talk');
        },
        listen: function()
        {
            alert(this.name + " is listening.");
        }
    });

Ext.define('Cats',
    {
        extend: 'Animal',
        name: 'Unknown',
        sound: 'Meow',
    });
Ext.define('Dogs',
    {
        extend: 'Animal',
        name: 'Unknown',
        sound: 'Woof',
    });
var cat1 = new Cats(
    {
        name: 'Domino',
        listeners:
        {
            talk: dog1.listen
        }
    });
var cat2 = Ext.create('Cats', 'Tiger');
var dog1 = Ext.create('Dogs', 'Bruno');
var dog2 = new Dogs(
    {
        name: 'Spot',
        listeners:
        {
            talk: cat2.listen
        }
    });

cat1.makeSound();
cat2.makeSound();
dog1.makeSound();
dog2.makeSound();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's really a bad idea to call one object methods directly from another object. You should consider re-designing you logic. If you need these classes/objects to communicate with each other you should either use the approach you described in your first sample, or you global events.

Comment: "It's really a bad idea to call one object methods directly from another object." - sha.
Are you referring to the listeners config? If so that's fine, I was just trying to think of other ways to finish the task in a similar way. 
Can you elaborate on why I shouldn't call a method directly from another object?

Comment: Your cat1 object should not know implementation detail of your dog1 object. And in your code cat1 object method calls dog1 methods directly. Dog1 can subscribe to events from cat1 on the other hand and perform its own functions in handlers.

Comment: Ah, ok. Thank you. You have convinced me to reconsider my question and so i will consider your answer the best answer.

Comment: this.listeners = this.listeners; // useless.